# php echo strange behavior

Tags: php, echo

I am just trying a simple test of php on my computer:

- Archlinux + httpd + php
- phpinfo() test is ok
- code is written with vim , no copy and paste

here is the code (taken from a book) that doesn't work as expected:

```
<html>
<head><title>Test PHP </title></head>
<body>
<h1>Texte mis en avant</h1>
<?php
echo "<p>ceci est du code PHP</p>";
echo "<p>simple non?</p>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is what I get in browsers:

> Texte mis en avant
>
> ceci est du code PHP
>
> "; echo "
>
> simple non?
>   "; ?>

What is wromg with this? (first time I block on something such simple)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default PHP script files have to be named with use of `.php` suffix, to be passed to PHP interpreter as the file name suffix is what is being taken into consideration during page serving. If you use `.html` as you said, then it simply goes as is, because HTML knows nothing about PHP. So you should either rename your file to end with `.php` (simplest approach) or tell your http server that `.html` files shall also be handled by PHP. I.e. if you are using Apache and `.htaccess` can be used per vhost, create `.htaccess` file in root of your service with content:

```
<FilesMatch "\.html$">
  ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

which will tell your httpd, that files matching given pattern shall also be considered PHP scripts.

Comment: thanks for your help, I was making modifications on my httpd.conf and I have added "AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php .html" in IfModule mime_module part of httpd.conf and it works. What is the best practice for you (I want this behavior to be by default)?

Comment: I'd suggest renaming all script files to `.php`. That way if for any reason you accidentally disable htaccess or change default config your PHP scripts body will not be exposed

Answer (score 2):

The PHP engine is not processing the page. View the page source to verify. Make sure that it is installed properly for that page.

Comment: I look at the source and you are right the code is not interpreted.

Answer (score -1):

Your file name should have extension **.php** and it is store in the the **document root** folder.

Change your file's extension from `html` to `php` and run again